# valgrind reporting errors on itself?

Tags: valgrind

I am running my program though valgrind, but it appears it is generating errors caused by the tool itself? All my errors look like the following, but from reading through other posts, it seems that usually the `at` line tells you where in your program the offending malloc occurs, but all my `at` lines are coming from valgrind. Are these legit errors in my program?

```
==10551== 32,808 (24 direct, 32,784 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss     record 840 of 843
==10551==    at 0x54D7: malloc_zone_malloc (in     /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.8.1/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==10551==    by 0x7C5171: NXCreateMapTableFromZone (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==10551==    by 0x7C4722: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==10551==    by 0x7C39EB: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==10551==    by 0x7C34F3: map_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==10551==    by 0x7FFF5FC04936: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==10551==    by 0x7FFF5FC0467C: dyld::registerImageStateBatchChangeHandler(dyld_image_states, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==10551==    by 0xA99ED9: dyld_register_image_state_change_handler (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==10551==    by 0x7C204C: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==10551==    by 0x6BB27: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==10551==    by 0x7FFF5FC13377: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==10551==    by 0x7FFF5FC13761: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==10551==
```

I used homebrew to install valgrind. It probably has something to do with this error:

```
==10551== WARNING: Support on MacOS 10.8 is experimental and mostly broken.
==10551== WARNING: Expect incorrect results, assertions and crashes.
```

but I just want to make sure (by someone who has used this before) that these errors are not coming from my program. (I am on 10.8).

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind replaces the default implementations of the library functions allocating and deallocating memory (malloc(), calloc(), realloc(), free() being the most important), by its own to track calls to them and do the bookkeeping. The backtrace shows the call stack to the malloc() call that allocated the memory that was never free()'d. So the problem doesn't lie in malloc() itself - but rather in the code calling malloc() without corresponding free().

Comment: but, none of those lines refer to my program anywhere. They are all pointing to /usr/lib/... and whatnot. So I suppose my code is fine.. will try running valgrind on linux.

Comment: Yes, if you read the backtrace, you see it's about dylib loading. Looks like a harmless one-time allocation of some "static" data structure when doing mmapping of the library code.

Answer (score 0):

The error-checking tools detect numerous problems in the system libraries, such as the C library, which come pre-installed with your OS. You can't easily fix these, but you don't want to see these errors (and yes, there are many!) So Valgrind reads a list of errors to suppress at startup. A default suppression file is created by the ./configure script when the system is built.

You can modify and add to the suppressions file at your leisure, or, better, write your own. Multiple suppression files are allowed. This is useful if part of your project contains errors you can't or don't want to fix, yet you don't want to continuously be reminded of them.

Note: By far the easiest way to add suppressions is to use the --gen-suppressions=yes option described in Core Command-line Options. This generates suppressions automatically. For best results, though, you may want to edit the output of --gen-suppressions=yes by hand, in which case it would be advisable to read through this section.

Each error to be suppressed is described very specifically, to minimise the possibility that a suppression-directive inadvertently suppresses a bunch of similar errors which you did want to see. The suppression mechanism is designed to allow precise yet flexible specification of errors to suppress.